# htaccess mod_rewrite css/js/images access issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using apache mod_rewrite, htaccess.

I find a way to achieve images/css/js file access without writing full url path in html/pages,  from some site,(i forgot the site).

So, I write in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule images/(.+)?$ images/$1 [NC,L]     # it take images from images folder
RewriteRule js/(.+)?$ js/$1 [NC,L]             # it take js files from js folder
RewriteRule topnav/(.+)?$ topnav/$1 [NC,L]     # it take js/css from topnav folder
RewriteRule common-style.css common-style.css # it take css from root folder
RewriteRule jquery.js jquery.js    # it take jquery from root folder
```

so, all js,css access.

but now i added another rule

```
RewriteRule script/js/(.+)?$ script/$1 [NC,L] # it should take js from script/js
```

it doesnot work.

i understand that now directory structure is two level i.e. script/js/ so it could not resolve file in "js" folder. but not know how to handle this.

I tried a lot, using different pattern, but faild.

Once again, My question is to access :

```
1) script/js/anyfile.js
2) script/css/anycssfile.css
3) script/blue_theme/Anyimagesfile.jpg
4) script/css/jquery/images/anyimages.jpg
```

Directory structure is as follow:

```
-script
        -js
        -css
           -jquery
                   -images       
        -blue_theme
```

Also, the path to fetch these resources is evaluated as by .httaccess:

http://localhost/site/Place-an-ad/Cars/Mazda/mazda-y/mazda-y-2/script/js/anyjsfile.js

but it is actualy at.
http://localhost/site/script/js/anyjsfile.js

Comment: actually, first i assign site url to a variable, and paste it with every relative url. like <?php $baseurl="http://localhost/site/";?> and paste as <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>script/blue_theme/style-blue.css" title="style_purple" media="screen" />  


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseurl;?>script/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.js"></script>  but it create design issue in dreamweaver, because css is inaccessible by dreamweaver in this case. thanks for ur response, but i want relative urls as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patterns do only match paths that either end with the given pattern (pattern ends with `$`) or just contains the given pattern (no `$`). And the problem is that the pattern `js/(.+)?$` will also match `script/js/` and so on.

Make your pattern more specific by providing both the start and the end of the path by using `^` and `$`:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)?$ images/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)?$ js/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^topnav/(.+)?$ topnav/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^common-style\.css$ common-style.css
RewriteRule ^jquery\.js$ jquery.js
```

And then do the same with your new rule:

```
RewriteRule ^script/js/(.+)?$ script/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you, you identify the real issue. js/ that comes in two rules and results in conflict.