# Url friendly without losing styles css / js / images

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have a website too extensive editing the URLs of styles `css` and files `js`, `images` would cost me too much time.

I'm working at localhost

```
localhost/project/index.php
```

The friendly url I want to have:

```
localhost/project/index/
```

From this url

```
localhost/project/online.php
```

to this

```
localhost/project/online/video/hd/free/
```

I have observed this website http://crazycafe.net/demos/seo/ and its source code, the styles `css` is maintained this way: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
without adding an **absolute URL** to styles `css` and their files and `images`.

How do i create a friendly url this way?

If the user modifies the url in this way:

```
http://crazycafe.net/demos/seo
```

Redirect to this way:

```
http://crazycafe.net/demos/seo/
```

On the other hand like conserving the styles `css` the files `js` and `images`, without having to modify to an absolute route.

My file directory is:

```
assets/css/style.css
assets/js/app.js
assets/fonts/icons/image.png
assets/fonts/ttf/roboto.ttf
assets/img/system/image.png
assets/img/logo.png
```

**Note:**

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932078/httaccess-mod-rewrite-css-js-images-acess-issue) in SO, of how conserve CSS styles.

But I do not understand the use of friendly URL - `.httaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch on **mod_rewrite** and use it. Example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Folder-based example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ http://gs.mt-example.com/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your case:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^online.php$ project/online/video/hd/free/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See more [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Comment: The code might be incompatible with your other code in .htaccess. Try to do a few experiments and let me know the results.

Comment: Hi! @LajosArpad The results are the ones that said server error does not display the page and shows that error.

Comment: And on this answer would not be useful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932078/httaccess-mod-rewrite-css-js-images-acess-issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932078/httaccess-mod-rewrite-css-js-images-acess-issue) @LajosArpad